# pandas: how to sort by one column and cut by another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, cut

newbie here... Have searched pandas docs and stackoverflow but can't find what I'm looking for.
Thanks in advance.

Let's say I want to sort a list of books in alphabetical order and place them in 3 different shelves such that they occupy roughly the same shelf space in each shelf.

I would expect to be able to:
1. sort the df by title
2. cut it in 3 by number_of_pages to get three bins with roughly the same number of total pages (even though each bin would have a different number of books)

```
df = DataFrame(data={"title": ['animal farm', 'cat in the hat', 'the great gatsby', 'to kill a mockingbird', 'war and peace'], "number_of_pages": [200, 20, 300, 250, 400]})
df = df.sort_values("title")
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df.number_of_pages, bins=3, labels=[0,1,2])
```

I would expect:

```
df
Out[34]: 
   number_of_pages                  title bin
0              200            animal farm   0
1               20         cat in the hat   0
2              300       the great gatsby   0
3              250  to kill a mockingbird   1
4              400          war and peace   2
```

but I get:

```
df
Out[34]: 
   number_of_pages                  title bin
0              200            animal farm   1
1               20         cat in the hat   0
2              300       the great gatsby   2
3              250  to kill a mockingbird   1
4              400          war and peace   2
```

So I have two problems:
1. cut sorts on the column that I am cutting instead of using the sorted DF
2. cut makes bins of the same number of books instead of roughly the same number of pages.

Comment: Your expected output does not seem to have "roughly the same number of pages" bin 0 has 520 pages, bin 2 has 250 (half of bin 1) and bin 3 has 400.

Comment: Given the two main constraints: 1) you cannot split up books and 2) you cannot change the order of the books... then that's the best you can do.  Think of the alternative... if you put "the great Gatsby" in bin 1 then you have 220, 550, 400 which would be worse

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

I needed to add a sum before the cut:

```
df = DataFrame(data={"title": ['animal farm', 'cat in the hat', 'the great gatsby', 'to kill a mockingbird', 'war and peace'], "number_of_pages": [200, 20, 300, 250, 400]})
df = df.sort_values("title")
df['cum'] = df.number_of_pages.cumsum()
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df.cum, bins=3, labels=[0,1,2])
```